# Invalid file name: 'файл'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

При попытке добавить папку/файл в андроид студио вылезает следуюшая ошибка:

> Invalid file name: 'файл'

Если же создать папку/файл через проводник, то она просто не отображается в студии и не попадает в APK, находясь в том же assets.

Comment: Почему проблема-то? Используйте латиницу. Это нормально

Comment: У нас на проекте на этом вся локализация основана. Есть 2 папка в assets, это ru и en. В en как понятно латиница, а в ru русское. Названия папок сами по себе являются локализатором в стиле tree

Comment: локализация чего? в папке assets лежат файлы, которые вы к проекту подгружаете. А если вам в UI нужно переключать русский/английский. это в другом месте

Comment: Тежело это тектсом обьяснить. У нас информационный проект, типо офлайн вики про автомобили. информация хранится в Markdown. И все саб катигории и т.д зависят от того как создать папки в assets. Вот пример. И имя папок автоматически подставляется в Grid 

https://imgur.com/a/aH7wWni

Comment: А раньше как работали?

Comment: Да, но в один момент у нас был перерыв, потом снос системы, а потом вот...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итого, нужно было просто поставить языковой пакет...)